# SharePoint Workflow 2010 is not triggering mail even after the expire date showing "In progress" still the date is lapsed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a workflow which is running fine for past 1 year suddenly today it is working in abnormal.

**The scenario is :**

Workflow has to get trigger the mail at 2 days once.

For Eg: 1st Mail has to go on : June/17/2016 , 2nd Mail has to go on June/20/2016 and 3rd Mail has to go on June/22/2016.

So actually today it has to trigger the mail but mail has not received. When I checked the workflow status was showing in Progress and message is "Pausing until June/20/2016", which is the second mail.

Any idea why the workflow status is "Pausing until June/20/2016" even the date has been lapsed?

Comment: Check whether SharePoint timer job service is running or not..

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could use the new flow app of Microsoft?
Flow.microsoft.com

Edit:
This is a workaround which may suit your needs.

- Go to flow.microsoft.com
- Search the templates for When an item in a SharePoint list is modified/added send an email.
- Adjust the template with the same conditions u have in your current workflow.

Congratulations your future proof now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63563)

Comment: Well it does provide a workaround for him. A workaround which could even be better than the way he tries now. Microsoft launched Flow this week so I guess he isn't aware of this function. Just trying to help this guy....

Comment: Then provide your answer with proper description or comment it

Comment: I can't comment... However I edited my post u satisfied now?